# How can I set up a "frozen highlighting row" in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Any suggestion on how to set up a highlighting horizontal row/window that remains in the same fixed position on the screen while I scroll up and down the rows? What I have in mind is a kind of horizontal freeze pane that allows rows to be highlighted when they pass through it when scrolling. To be more clear, let's say that now I have the row 20 highlighted. If i scroll down 1 row, now I have the row 21 highlighted, and so on. Like if I'd place a colored transparent tape on my monitor, and the rows get highlighted when they pass under it. Is it possible to set up a macro or VBA code to do this?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to change the background color of every row that has been selected at least once?

Comment: To be honest, sticking a length of colored transparent plastic to your monitor may be the quickest solution.

Comment: @teylyn Lol! Isn't there a macro that changes the background color of every row that's distant e.g. 20 rows from the top of the screen?

Comment: Not exactly, LPChip. I would like to set up something similar to a sort of "digital tape" across my spreadsheet that's always locked in the same position and doesn't move with the cells as I scroll up and down my spreadsheet. A sort of filter that changes the color of a row passing through it.

Comment: Is it possible to lock a shape or object in a fixed position from the top of the spreadsheet, that doesn't move when I scroll up and down?

Comment: Well, there may be a macro that does this, but unfortunately, this site is not a free code writing service. You're welcome to ask questions if you run into problems with your approach or get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The main challenge is detecting the scroll event ([details on CPearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DetectScroll.htm))

If you want to scroll using the Up and Down arrows (keyboard only) try the code bellow

In ThisWorkbook module add:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    HighlightCurrentRow Sh, Target
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

---

In a standard module add:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub HighlightCurrentRow(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ur As Range, thisRow As Long, prevRow As Long, found As Range
    Dim back1 As Long, fore1 As Long, back2 As Long, fore2 As Long

    back2 = RGB(111, 0, 0)      'Background color - dark red
    fore2 = RGB(255, 255, 0)    'Foreground color - yellow

    Set ur = Sh.UsedRange
    thisRow = Target.Row

    Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = back2
    Set found = ur.Cells.Find(What:="", After:=ur.Cells(1), SearchFormat:=True)

    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        prevRow = IIf(found.Row < ur.Rows.Count, found.Row + 1, found.Row - 1)
        back1 = ur.Cells(prevRow, ur(1).Column).Interior.Color
        fore1 = ur.Cells(prevRow, ur(1).Column).Font.Color
        ur.Rows(found.Row).Interior.Color = back1
        ur.Rows(found.Row).Font.Color = fore1
    End If

    If Target.Row > 1 And Not Intersect(ur, Target) Is Nothing Then
        If thisRow > 15 Then Application.ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = thisRow - 15
        ur.Rows(thisRow).Interior.Color = back2
        ur.Rows(thisRow).Font.Color = fore2
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Now on any sheet, when you click a cell with data, the entire row will be highlighted with a dark red background and yellow font

If the active cell is in row 16 or higher the window will scroll up or down (the scroll row is offset by 15 rows) and the active row will be highlighted, but if the cell is outside of the UsedRange no rows will be highlighted

[image: Sheet1]

Answer (score 0):

**@design95, on your demand I would like to show you that how you can highlight every 20th Row, count from Row 1.**

Follow these steps.

1. Select the Data Range like (A1:Az1000).
2. Go to Conditional Formatting.
3. Hit New Rule & select option Use Formula which format.
4. Write this Formula.

=AND(($A1=1),MOD(ROW($A1),**20**)=0)

5. Finally select the Fill Colour & others.

**NB:** Value 20 is Row number, can be replaced with other as your  need.

**Next is how to Highlight the Row you select or the Active Row.**

Follow all FOUR previous steps and write this Formula,

=CELL("row")=ROW()

Finish with selecting Colours and others.

The final one is, Right click the Sheet TAB, hit View Code and write this simple code.

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As range)

Application.Calculate

End Sub

**Hope this help you. Drop your comment.**

Comment: The second formula worked straight away, it highlights any row I select, however I'm not able to get the first formula working. I selected a range of cells with no blank rows or columns, trying with and without the 3 lines of code you added, saving the file as macro-enabled, still nothing. It could be due to the same reason that I can't run all the macros that I find on the web either. Thanks a lot for your time, anyway! :)

Comment: The first Formula is as simple as I've written and the "Application.Calculated"  is just like Refresh, you can use F9 for that.Try it in a New Sheet once.

Comment: Now the first formula works on a new sheet! However it's frozen with row #20 (absolute), it doesn't update automatically and highlight the current 20th row of the *visible range* any time I scroll up or down. Is there a way to implement the visible range property in the context of this conditional formatting?

Comment: YES, its very much possible using VBA and Non-VBA both. As Non-VBA solution Subtotal function is very common to use, like =Subtotal(105,$A$2:$D$10).